# CSS - Fill remaining height (dynamic content)

Tags: css

```
<div id="header">
    <div>My</div>
    <div>Header</div>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

In the above markup, how can I get the content to fill the rest of the screen (no-scrolling)?
I know how to do this with absolute positions if the header was of a fixed height, but my header's height is dynamically set by its contents (so the site is responsive on mobile devices.)

Btw: I'm looking for a CSS only solution, because I think JavaScript is not made for this kind of task.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: What happens if `#header` is taller than the screen? Or if `#content`'s content is taller than the remaining space?

Comment: In that case scroll would be added, but my intention is not to have the contents of #header or #content filling up the entire screen.

Comment: Any chance of a http://jsfiddle.net/ of what you have attempted so far?

Comment: I'm pretty jsfiddle-less at the moment because I'm on my phone, but I'm at a loss for how it would be done when the header has a dynamic height. Absolute positioning works great if the header has a fixed height, but I can't see it working with a dynamic header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simpliest way is to draw the background in body and keep `#content` translucide. **[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/PS4Z2/)**.

This way, you do not mind `#header` nor `#content` heights.

---

If you do not mind about IE7 and less, then `display:table/table-row/table-cell` taken from defaut `display` of HTML table elements can be what you need , ***in the case header has unknown height***. **[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/YnR9S/)**

Your structure will need a bit of update in order to act as wished and to avoid gaps in layout render from header part to the content part.

If you reset `display` to be used as table properties, it will do so and can draw cols and rows.

Since it is only the row properties that will be usefull, Structure must be rendering as one single col and multiple rows.

Basic structure needs to turn this way :

```
<div id="header" class="row">
    <div class="single">
        <div>My</div>
        <div>Header than can grow</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content" class="row">
    <div class="single">
        <p>My Content that will fill remaining space untill page has to scroll</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And basic CSS turns this way :

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}
body {
    display:table;/* it will allow to grow over initial width specified */
    /* table-layout:fixed; only if you want to control width within value specified*/
    background:#edc;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;/* we want these elements to stack on top of each other, not to become cells aside each other */
}
.single {
    display:table-cell;/* this 'buffer' element is used to avoid layout to turn into multiple cols */
}
#content {
    height:100%;/* since layout is the one taken from table properties, it means  fill all space avalaible that #header doesn't use */
    background:#cde;
}
```

---

***In the case, **#header** has a known*** `height`, it can be set in fixed or absolute position.
`#content` can be 100% `height` **[DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/PS4Z2/1/)**, better: `min-height:100%;` **[DEMO 4](http://jsfiddle.net/PS4Z2/2/)**

`display:flex` could be useful too but for real young browser only :).

---

**[Example with](http://jsfiddle.net/PS4Z2/6/)** `display:flex;`

```
html {
    height:100%;
}
body {
    margin:0;
    min-height:100%;
    background:#edc;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}
#header {
/* nothing needed here */
}
#content {
    flex:1;/* since it is the only one getting a flex attitude, it will fill up all space avalaible*/
    background:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, I found that Demo 2 was the best answer, see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YnR9S/2/). With Demo 1 I couldn't get the height of the content to be 100%, and Demo 3 & 4 we're for headers of fixed height. Btw, if you know any solutions that don't use tables I'd love to hear (I'll look into display: flex, this is just a personal project so I don't mind if it's a new feature.)

Comment: @PaulVon for the display:flex; this demo should be minimal rules necessary to have the desired layout : http://jsfiddle.net/PS4Z2/4/ . take a look at different tutorial on the internet to find out all possibilities with all rules attached to it :) BTW display:table and <table> are nothing alike, it is default CSS rules for HTML table elements. display:list-item; to a <div> will never turn a <div> into <li>, it might just look alike

Comment: Thanks a lot @GCyrillus, I trying to make a demo myself with flex but didn't finish.